# Routes and namespaces on filtered index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an event model and an events_type model. All events are assigned an id from the event_type model.

In my event index action/view I have a filter that allows me to filter and view events of a chosen type by looking for an id passed in the url. For example; **http:localhost:3000/events?event_type=2**

What i'd like to do is have this work with the event_type name instead like this; **http:localhost:3000/events/film** etc and i'd also like to be able to provide unique metatags for each event_type (which will probably mean a migration to add fields to my event_type model).

Can anyone offer some help on how to approve this? Would it simply be a routing/namespace thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to diverge from the `resources` method in your routes to add dynamic functionality. That's okay, I actually prefer doing so, as stated below my answer.

The basic strategy is to rewrite what `resources` does ourselves, adding in an extra route endpoint that can catch your `:event_type`. In this case, we effectively insert your `:event_type` routes before anything that would override it.

```
# routes.rb

# We want the vanilla index route to come first, then deal with the rest.
# Notice it receives no params.
get 'events'           to: 'events#index'

# Using scope or namespace gives us urls nested under that string:
#  /events/:event_type
# Using scope instead of namespace prevents the router for looking under a corresponding ruby module
# AKA if this was `namespace 'event_type' do`, it would look for a
#   `Events::EventsController#index` instead of using our `EventsController#index`.
# All of the `as:` statements are to preserve access to the standard
#   path+url helpers you get out of the box with `resources`.
# All of the `constraints:` are to prevent urls from overriding each other.
#   I don't believe they're strictly necessary in this example, but
#   explicit is better than implicit in your routes.
scope 'events' do
  get ':event_type/:meta',  to: 'events#index',     as: :event_by_type_and_meta, constraints: { :event_type => /[a-zA-Z]*/, :meta => /[a-zA-Z]*/ }
  get ':event_type',  to: 'events#index',     as: :event_by_type, constraints: { :event_type => /[a-zA-Z]*/ }
  get ':id/edit',     to: 'events#edit',      as: :edit_event,   constraints: { :id => /\d/ }
  get 'new',          to: 'events#new',       as: :new_event

  delete ':id',       to: 'events#destroy',   as: :delete_event, constraints: { :id => /\d/ }
  put ':id',          to: 'events#update',    as: :update_event, constraints: { :id => /\d/ }
  get ':id',          to: 'events#show',      as: :event,        constraints: { :id => /\d/ }

  post '',            to: 'events#create',     as: :create_event
  get '',             to: 'events#index',     as: :events
end
```

With that in place, you can just check for `:event_type` in your `EventController` and filter accordingly. If using the `:meta` tag, just refine the filter further.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:event_type]
      @event_type = EventType.find_by_name(params[:event_type])
      @events = Event.includes(:event_types).where(["id NOT IN (?)", @event_type.events_ids]).all
    else
      @event_type = nil
      @events = Event.filed_under(@event_type).all
    end
  end
```

If you're not making a RESTful API, in my opinion you should avoid using `resources` period. The very first part of your app your users will encounter is your URL structure. It's really the most overlooked facet of the user experience. Stating all your routes explicitly helps your think through that experience, as well as assert the finer grained control I'm using below.

It's also easy to leave routes in that really shouldn't be exposed if you just use `resource`. Being explicit with your URLs helps you be aware of security vulnerabilities.

Comment: This looks spot on, i'll give it a try today. Thanks for such an in depth answer!

Comment: this is working really well thanks, but I've run into an issue I didn't initially consider; how can I handle my event show if I were to move to using a slug instead of the id? At the moment events/great-band-live would be treated as an event_type by the routing above.

Comment: That would complicate things. Off the top of my head the easiest way at this point would be to namespace the event's event_types url to something like 'events/type/:event_type'.

Comment: Cool, fairly obvious but that seems to work. Out of interest, what's your thinking behind the first route `get ':event_type/:meta'`, not currently using this and had to comment out to get 'events/type/:event_type' to work. Finally, made a small mod to the regex to handle hyphens so we now have /[a-zA-Z-]*/

Comment: Your original question mentioned that you'd "also like to be able to provide unique metatags for each event_type", I was just throwing something out there.

Comment: Ah, I see, I meant I wanted to change the title/keywords/description etc which I have managed through addition fields in the db. Thanks again for your help.